# Build ajQuery Mobile ListView from Ajax JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm new at jQuery Mobile and I need to build a dynamic application to, in the future, import to PhoneGap.

For that, I'm avoiding the MVC4 mobile cshtml files, and building html/ajax pages.

In the homePage of the application I have a static ListView, and when I click in an option, I want to call a WebApi method, return JSON data and build a ListView in the application.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**js**

```
var html = "";
$.getJSON('url', function (data) {
    for (var i in data) {
        html += "<li> <a class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r'>here json text</a></li>";
    }
    $("#ul-menu").append(html);
}).done(function () {
    $('#ul-menu').listview().listview('refresh');
});
```

**html**

```
<ul id="ul-menu" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview"></ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! how can I pass information from the init page like the id of the selected listView item, to build the second page listView?

Comment: elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @kathir how do I get the click from the first listView, extract the Id to send by Ajax and retrieve the list to a new page with this listView?

Comment: It's not going to a new page, it reloads in the same page

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Notification Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<!--   <link href="css/mobipick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->

<!-- js -->

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
    ;
    }
$(function(){
    var html="";
    for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
        html+="<li><a>Acura"+i+"</a></li>";
    }

        $("#ul-topmenu").append(html)   
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#ul-topmenu").listview().listview("refresh");
        },300);
        $('#ul-topmenu li a').click(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
              $.ajax({
                  url: "put url here",
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType:"json",
                  data:$(this).text(),
                  success:function(result) {

                  }
              });
        })
});


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ul-topmenu" data-role="listview">
        <li><a>Acura</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```